# How to validate CHOICES for objects.create() method?

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models


class Artist(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Person', 'Person'),
        ('Group', 'Group'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

The problem is that if I create an object like this:
`Artist.objects.create(...)` the type validation doesn't work.
How can I activate the validation for this?

Comment: Normally it does not even check this when you construct an object like `a = Artist()` and then `artist.save()` it. This is done in the `artist.clean()` function, and this is normally only called in forms, etc.

Comment: I've just added super().clean() in the save method but it doesn't work.

Comment: Added the `super().clean()` *where*?

Comment: In the save() method from the model.

Comment: But you then should call `self.clean()`, since now you look for the *previous* clean method. You also need to call `self.clean_fields()`, and `self.validate_unique()`.

Comment: Ah great thanks, that's working. I wonder why Django doesn't do this by default.

Comment: If I recall correctly, due to performance reasons. Note that `bulk_create`, and `SomeModel.objects.all().update(..)`, etc. can still surpass this (since some ORM calls circumvent `.save()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an (abstract) model that first performs validations before saving the object with:

```
class ValidatedModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean_fields()      # validate individual fields
        self.clean()             # validate constraints between fields
        self.validate_unique()   # validate uniqness of fields
        return super(ValidatedModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then for example use this in models like:

```
class Artist(ValidatedModel):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Person', 'Person'),
        ('Group', 'Group'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Note that the above will validate model object in case you call the `.save()` method (or some other function does that), but some methods circumvent calling the `.save()` method like `Model.objects.bulk_create(..)`, etc.